# kubectl apply -f <file_name> where does it apply to?

Tags: json, kubernetes

I am trying to do the prerequisites mentioned in https://hub.helm.sh/charts/jetstack/cert-manager

```
$ kubectl apply \
    -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.11/deploy/manifests/00-
```

I tried to figure out what `kubectl apply` does since I joined a project with k8s already up and running and therefore having not much basic knowledge.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply

The guide says:

Apply the configuration in `pod.json` to a pod.

`kubectl apply -f ./pod.json`

But I don't get why in this command no target is mentioned. I expected something like:

`kubectl apply -f ./pod.json application-pod-01`

But nowhere is an explicit target for this `apply` command of the file mentioned. I am sure I am missing a crucial concept here but can't figure it out by reading up the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most objects in the kubernetes API have a namespace and a name (if namespace is left out of the definition it defaults to the `default` namespace), defined in the [ObjectMetaData](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#objectmeta-v1-meta).

In the yaml file you will see the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: application-pod
  namespace: my-namespace
```

The combination of name and namespace uniquily identify the object in Kubernetes, and allow kubernetes to find a specific instance  of the object (e.g. `pod-01`) and update it (most likely creating a new instance of the object, e.g. `pod-02`).

Comment: Just a small addition: not all resources are namespaced e.g. `pv`, `clusterrole` or similar :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax

kubectl apply -f pod.json

OR

kubectl apply -f pod.yaml

Answer (score 0):

First, it is helpful to understand that there are two ways of deploying stuff in k8s: declarative and imperative. Long story short, by doing stuff imperatively, you make it once and for "single use"; by doing it declaratively, you do it for prolonged usage.

What you did there is you used declarative way of deploying. It's indicated that you used command "apply" that deploy object in declarative way.

What it really does:

1. It read all information about an object from a .yaml file
2. It checks the state of a cluster (it looks for something that is called **operator**).
3. Perform operations on a cluster to meet a **desired state**

The **operator** part is something that I'm not 100% sure so if anyone can dive into more details it will be great. As far as I know every declaratively deployed resource has it's own operator that sits deep into k8s cluster and take care of a specific resource. That's why if you will declaratively deploy a pod and then delete it by "kubectl delete pod" it will come back after a while. Operator of that specific resource will notice that the **actual state** of cluster doesn't meet **desired state** and will change it's state.

The same happens if you do secend "kubectl apply pod.yaml" but now istead of changing actual state you change desired state. In that case state of k8s cluster remain the same but a desired state changes and we end in a situation when resource operator need to intervene.

And as it was said, a namespace.name is a definite identifier of a resource (similar like ID) so you need to  specify all innformation about a pod in pod.yaml. That's why your command  "kubectl apply pod.yaml" know what to look for as that operattor that I mentioned will contain the same information in desired state definition.

Further research:
Declarative vs. imperative: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/15055/declarative-vs-imperative-kubernetes-object-management/